# React native creation of an android module .gitignore file

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gitignore

React-native creation of an android module `.gitignore` file

I'm creating a module that will then be on npm, the question is how should I set the gitignore file for android?

Must it be placed in the root folder or in the `/android` folder?

Looking on the internet I found something like this:

```
# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
```

it's correct? Where should I put it to correctly insert it to work?

1) In the `/Android` folder, I have the following dir and files, which can I delete?

```
.idea
gradle/wrapper
build.gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
settings.gradle
```

Which are useful for the project and which are not?
The `.gitignore` I have to put it here?

2) In the `/android/app` folder, I have the following files, which ones can I delete?

```
build.gradle
proguard-rules.pro
```

Example the: /android/build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Do you need something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can update **.gitignore** sample to prepend **android/** to all Android file paths. The **.gitignore** file will still live in the base directory **/** of your ReactNative project.

So your **.gitignore** would contain lines like this for Android:

```
android/app/build
android/build
```

Lastly I suggest you find projects on Github to guide you, such as this one:
https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-react-native